# $_FILES is empty when I load images with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form to edit existing data but for some reason the images I load are not being detected in the var $_FILES.

The var $_FILES only detect data If I upload more images manually (without javascript code).

Here is my code to load images to the form.

```js
// This images are loaded after the query is executed and then 
// I take this images and insert in the form.
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("image-product");   
var dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

for (let image of images) {
  fetch(image.src).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {
    var file = new File([blob], image.id, blob);
    dataTransfer.items.add(file);
    listImagesForm.push(file);
  });
}

var iptImg = document.getElementById("ipt-image");
iptImg.files = dataTransfer.files;
```

But if I go to the console and execute the command: document.getElementById("ipt-image").files I can see the information of all files.

[image]

**EDIT:**

The code that I use to submit form is simple:

```html
<form class='form-validate' action='./database/db_product.php?action=update' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>;
  <input type="file" multiple class="custom-file-input" id="ipt-image" name="ipt-image[]">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

I remember again that if I upload more images after this they will be added to existing ones and the $_FILES will detect all the images.

Comment: Where in your code are you submitting or serializing the form?

Comment: @Sam sorry but I didn't understand your question.

Comment: What is `listImagesForm`? Is it the form object? You don't show in your code how you get it.  That is all happening in the client, while `$_FILES` exists only on the server so, as Sam says, unless you send that to the server by submitting the form or otherwise serializing it, it can't be seen on the server. You don't show in your code that you're doing anything like that.

Comment: @StephenP Oh I understand. Basically the listImagesForm is an array to manage the list images because I have another functionalities and Instead of acess everytime to the form I use that list. I edited the question with the code that I use to submit form.